# What does Hibernate map a boolean datatype to when using an Oracle database by default?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, orm

By default if I create a field in an entity like:

```
@NotNull
boolean myBoolean;
```

And I let Hibernate auto-create my tables. What Oracle data type will this map to?

Comment: Does the annotation there has any meaning for the generated schema?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply Number(1)

If you want, use SchemaExport to generate a script to your target database. Something like

```
AnnotationConfiguration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration();

configuration
    .addAnnotatedClass(<TYPE_YOUR_CLASS>.class)
    .setProperty(Environment.USER, <TYPE_YOUR_USER>)
    .setProperty(Environment.PASS, <TYPE_YOUR_PASSWORD>)
    .setProperty(Environment.URL, <TYPE_YOUR_URL>)
    .setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, <TYPE_YOUR_DIALECT>)
    .setProperty(Environment.DRIVER, <TYPE_YOUR_DRIVER>);

SchemaExport schema = new SchemaExport(configuration);
schema.setOutputFile("schema.sql");

schema.create(<DO_YOU_WANT_TO_PRINT_TO_THE_CONSOLE>, <DO_YOU_WANT_TO_EXPORT_THE_SCRIPT_TO_THE_DATABASE>);
```

Answer (score 62):

As @Arthur said it maps to `Number(1)` which would be the standard sql bit where `0 == false` and `1 == true`. As an alternative you can map `char(1)` to 'T' or 'F' like this

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="true_false")
@NotNull
boolean myBoolean;
```

or map it to 'Y' or 'N'

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type="yes_no")
@NotNull
boolean myBoolean;
```

Comment: would an xml example be possible as well?

Comment: @rogerdpack <property name="myBoolean" type="true_false" /> or <property name="myBoolean" type="yes_no" />

Answer (score 10):

This is what you really need

**Java POJO**:

```
//@Type(type="true_false") //not working for '1' and '0' in NUMERIC(1) field
@Type(type= "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
@NotNull(message="NOT_NULL")
@Column(name = "IS_DELEGATION", nullable = false)
private Boolean isDelegation;
```

**Oracle DDL**

```
alter table agent add (is_delegation number(1) default 0 not null);
```

As stated in 
[Hibernate docu](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/NumericBooleanType.html)