# Hide items from collection

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two classes ;

```
 User {
        private String name;
        private Set<Role> roles;
    }

Role {
    private String name;
    private boolean disabled;
}
```

In my application a user can get multiple roles assigned, these are stored in the Set of roles.
It can occur that a role gets disabled and should no longer viewable by the users.

I am using Hibernate Criteria to query the tables;

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", name));
```

Is there a way to query the user table and use this query to also 'hide' the disabled roles from his/her Set of roles of should I handle this after I ran my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way, you can use [@Where](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection) annotation. It is Hibernate proprietary annotation and I don't like proprietary annotations, but it fits your case.
Sorry for the old links, but in the latest manual of Hibernate I don't find a good explanation for this annotation, though it is still valid.

Comment: I ended up using the xml variant; http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-class

Comment: @MrThys, actually since the code you posted didn't contain annotation, I could have pointed you directly to xml. I am now used to annotation. But glad I at least pointed you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

You can perform an [inner join](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins) using HQL.

**HQL**

```
SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.roles r WHERE r.disabled = 0
```

This assumes you have setup your `boolean` to map to a column of type `Number(1)`

[What does Hibernate map a boolean datatype to when using an Oracle database by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710198/what-does-hibernate-map-a-boolean-datatype-to-when-using-an-oracle-database-by-d)

**Hibernate Criteria**

```
List users = sess.createCriteria(User.class)
    .createCriteria("roles")
        .add( Restrictions.like("disabled", new Integer(0)))
    .list();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I am using Hibernate Criteria to query the tables, is there a way to solve it using that?

Comment: @MrThys What type is your boolean in the database?

Comment: Number(1) like you assumed

Comment: @MrThys Do you have your mappings setup via annotations or xml?  If you setup the sql to show what sql command is being issued?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should encapsulate this by implementing accessor method for roles into `User` class. This method will return only enabled roles. This fixes problem of hiding disabled roles.
2. Other problem is removing role once it is disabled from role list of all users. You can do it as following. create special service/manger that is responsible on users/roles related operations. Implement method `disableRole()` that does the following: makes role disabled and then iterates over all users and removes role from their roles list. But be careful: in this case role will not appear automatically in users lists once it is enabled again. So, I'd implement only first idea (see above).