# Why does SqlExceptionHelper interpret boolean constraint violation as \x00

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following domain object

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"name", "company_id", "global"}, name="UC_name_companyId_global")})
@Entity
@Audited
public class AccessLevel implements Serializable, GlobalEntityInstance {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7215569721971710808L;

  @Size(min = 2)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false)
  private Company company;

  @Column
  private boolean global = false;

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private GeneralStatus status;
}
```

The `company` attribute is mapped to column `company_id`.

I've created a test case to test that when an Access Level is added with the same 'name', 'company' and 'global' value a `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown.
The excetion is being thrown, my questions is about the message:

`o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Duplicate entry 'Temp Level-1-\x00' for key 'UC_name_companyId_global'`

What in the heck is '\x00' (or '\x01' if true is saved) and why does the SqlExceptionHelper map/resolve a boolean value to it?
Shouldnt the Duplicate entry key be 'Temp Level-1-false'?

Thanks in advance, 
Grant

**UPDATE:**

Im currently using MySQl 5.6

Comment: what is the underlying column type?

Comment: You can read about storing boolean in mysql in : [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-data-type-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values)

Comment: An a similar question but on Oracle : [What does Hibernate map a boolean datatype to when using an Oracle database by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710198/what-does-hibernate-map-a-boolean-datatype-to-when-using-an-oracle-database-by-d)

Answer (score 2):

`\x00` is hex `0`, and `\x01` is hex `1`. Commonly (but **not** always) used  values for `false` and `true`. MySQL for example stores boolean columns as `BIT(1)`, so it's working with `0/1` internally instead of `true/false`.

Comment: Well, good thing they intend to fully implement booleans after version 5.1 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11881

Comment: @Kayaman, Thanks for pointing this out. Do you know why the boolean is being mapped to a hex value?

Comment: @ThatGuyGrant I don't really know why they chose hex representation for it instead of decimal, but since there's no concept of `true/false` at that level, it's going to show up in *some* number format.